# Comparing multiple numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

how should i compare more than 2 numpy arrays?

```
import numpy 
a = numpy.zeros((512,512,3),dtype=numpy.uint8)
b = numpy.zeros((512,512,3),dtype=numpy.uint8)
c = numpy.zeros((512,512,3),dtype=numpy.uint8)
if (a==b==c).all():
     pass
```

this give a valueError, and i am not interested in comparing arrays two at a time.

Comment: "and i am not interested in comparing arrays two at a time" - well, it's the best option you have.

Comment: @user2357112 that wouldn't be easy if there are many arrays

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For three arrays, you can check for equality among the corresponding elements between the first and second arrays and then second and third arrays to give us two boolean scalars and finally see if both of these scalars are `True` for final scalar output, like so  -

```
np.logical_and( (a==b).all(), (b==c).all() )
```

For more number of arrays, you could stack them, get the differentiation along the axis of stacking and check if **all** of those differentiations are equal to zeros. If they are, we have equality among all input arrays, otherwise not. The implementation would look like so -

```
L = [a,b,c]    # List of input arrays
out = (np.diff(np.vstack(L).reshape(len(L),-1),axis=0)==0).all()
```

Comment: what is the need of reshape(len(L),-1), it works well even without that

Comment: @JayanthReddy No, it doesn't. That axis would contain the first axis from the input arrays merged with the axis of stacking. So, we need to split that axis into two with that reshaping. To clarify with an example, try out with `a = np.random.randint(0,9,(4,5,3)); b = a.copy(); c = a.copy()`.

Answer (score 8):

For three arrays, you should really just compare them two at a time:

```
if np.array_equal(a, b) and np.array_equal(b, c):
    do_whatever()
```

For a variable number of arrays, let's suppose they're all combined into one big array `arrays`. Then you could do

```
if np.all(arrays[:-1] == arrays[1:]):
    do_whatever()
```

Comment: @JayanthReddy: Probably because you made `arrays` a list or something.

Answer (score 6):

To expand on previous answers, I would use `combinations` from `itertools` to construct all pairs, then run your comparison on each pair. For example, if I have three arrays and want to confirm that they're all equal, I'd use:

```
from itertools import combinations

for pair in combinations([a, b, c], 2):
    assert np.array_equal(pair[0], pair[1])
```

Comment: constructing all pairs is not necessary (since a=b and b=c would imply a=c). A simple for loop comparing 2 arrays at a time would be more computationally efficient.

Comment: That's correct! This is explicitly inefficient. Just a method for intuitively/transparently comparing each item to the others.

Comment: This answer is useful for `float` arrays where you'd want to use [`allclose`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html) instead of `array_equal`; `allclose` is not [transitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_relation). @Elsewhere Maybe you could expand your answer based on that since the question doesn't explicitly ask for comparing for equality and neither restricts to `int` arrays.

Answer (score 1):

## solution supporting different shapes and nans

compare against first element of array-list:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(3)
b = np.arange(3)
c = np.arange(3)
d = np.arange(4)

lst_eq = [a, b, c]
lst_neq = [a, b, d]

def all_equal(lst):
    for arr in lst[1:]:
        if not np.array_equal(lst[0], arr, equal_nan=True):
            return False
    return True

print('all_equal(lst_eq)=', all_equal(lst_eq))
print('all_equal(lst_neq)=', all_equal(lst_neq))
```

**output**

```
all_equal(lst_eq)= True
all_equal(lst_neq)= False
```

## for equal shape and without nan-support

Combine everything into one array, calculate the absolute diff along the new axis and check if the maximum element along the new dimension is equal 0 or lower than some threshold. This should be quite fast.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(3)
b = np.arange(3)
c = np.arange(3)
d = np.array([0, 1, 3])

lst_eq = [a, b, c]
lst_neq = [a, b, d]

def all_equal(lst, threshold = 0):
    arr = np.stack(lst, axis=0)

    return np.max(np.abs(np.diff(arr, axis=0))) <= threshold

print('all_equal(lst_eq)=', all_equal(lst_eq))
print('all_equal(lst_neq)=', all_equal(lst_neq))
```

**output**

```
all_equal(lst_eq)= True
all_equal(lst_neq)= False
```

Answer (score 1):

one-liner solution:

```
arrays = [a, b, c]    
all([np.array_equal(a, b) for a, b in zip(arrays, arrays[1:])])
```

We test the equality of consecutive pairs of arrays

Comment: While this piece of code may answer the question, it is recommended to add some explaination on what it does.

Answer (score 0):

This might work.

```py
import numpy

x = np.random.rand(10)
arrays = [x for _ in range(10)]

print(np.allclose(arrays[:-1], arrays[1:]))  # True

arrays.append(np.random.rand(10))

print(np.allclose(arrays[:-1], arrays[1:]))  # False
```